# How to integrate $\int \frac{4}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In order to solve the following integral:

$$\int \frac{4}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$

I tried different things such as getting $u = x^2 + 1$, $u=x^2$ but it seems that it does not work. I also tried moving $x$ to the radical and writing the denominator as $\sqrt{x^4-x^2}$ but it also didn't work. Its look reminds me of $$\int \frac {1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) +c$$ but there is an extra $x$ in the denominator that I can't get rid of.

Comment: Try $x=sec\theta$

Comment: try a substitution $x=\cosh(t)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have, taking $u=\sqrt{x^{2}-1}
 $, $$\int\frac{4}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx=4\int\frac{1}{u^{2}+1}du.
 $$ I think you can get from here. Expanding a little bit, note that $$ u=\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\Rightarrow du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx
 $$ and $$ x^{2}=u^{2}+1
 $$ then $$4\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx=4\int\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx=4\int\frac{1}{u^{2}+1}du.
 $$.

Answer (score 4):

set $t=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ then we get $$dx=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}dt$$ and we get $$\int\frac{4dt}{t^2+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

We have, $$\int \frac{4}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$ 
Let, $x=sec\alpha\implies dx=\sec\alpha\tan \alpha d\alpha $ $$=\int \frac{4\sec\alpha\tan \alpha d\alpha}{\sec\alpha\sqrt{\sec^2\alpha-1}}dx $$
$$=4\int \frac{\tan \alpha d\alpha}{\tan\alpha}dx =4\int d\alpha=4\alpha+C=4\sec^{-1}(x)+C$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Since $\frac {d}{dx}arcsec(x)=\frac {1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, I think one another solution would be $4\cdot arcsec|x|+C$

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: I saw the formula in the book, you wrote its proof :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x\ge 1$, set $x=\cosh u,\enspace u\ge0$. Then you have:
\begin{align*}\int\frac{4\sinh u\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{\cosh u\sqrt{\cosh^2u-1 }}=4\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{\cosh u}=8\int\frac{\mathrm e^u\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{\mathrm e^{2u}+1}=8\arctan\mathrm e^u=8\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}).
\end{align*}
If $x\le-1$, setting $x=-\cosh u,\enspace u\ge 0$, we obtain the same integral, hence $$x=-8\arctan(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}).$$

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $x=1/u$ will take you to the arcsin integral that you recognize.

(Treat the cases $x>1$ and $x<-1$ separately.)